# Remove prefix from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to remove prefix from one element (Description) in the xml below, however it is getting deleted from the final output -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:NAXML-MaintenanceRequest version="" xmlns:ns0="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16">
   <ns0:TransmissionHeader>
      <ns0:StoreLocationID/>
      <ns0:VendorName/>
      <ns0:VendorModelVersion/>
   </ns0:TransmissionHeader>
   <ns0:ItemMaintenance>
      <ns0:TableAction type=""/>
      <ns0:RecordAction type=""/>
      <ns0:ITTDetail>
         <ns0:RecordAction type="" effectiveDate="" effectiveTime=""/>
         <ns0:ItemCode>
            <ns0:POSCodeFormat format=""/>
            <ns0:POSCode/>
            <ns0:POSCodeModifier name=""/>
         </ns0:ItemCode>
         <ns0:ITTData>
            <ns0:ActiveFlag value=""/>
            <ns0:InventoryValuePrice/>
            <ns0:MerchandiseCode/>
            <ns0:RegularSellPrice/>
            <ns0:Description/>
            <ns0:FamilyCode/>
            <ns0:ItemType>
               <ns0:ItemTypeCode/>
               <ns0:ItemTypeSubCode/>
            </ns0:ItemType>
            <ns0:LinkCode type=""/>
            <ns0:PaymentSystemsProductCode/>
            <ns0:SalesRestrictCode/>
            <ns0:SellingUnits uom=""/>
            <ns0:TaxStrategyID/>
         </ns0:ITTData>
         <ns0:ITTDetailExtension>
            <ns0:ModifierID required=""/>
            <ns0:DeviceGroupID/>
            <ns0:CondimentItemListID/>
            <ns0:ComboItemListID/>
            <ns0:SalesRestrictionStrategyID/>
            <ns0:InventoryItem>
               <ns0:Description/>
               <ns0:PriceUOMFactor uomId=""/>
            </ns0:InventoryItem>
            <ns0:ProhibitOnPOSFlag value=""/>
         </ns0:ITTDetailExtension>
      </ns0:ITTDetail>
   </ns0:ItemMaintenance>
</ns0:NAXML-MaintenanceRequest>
```

XSLT -

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns0 ns1">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:NAXML-MaintenanceRequest">
        <NAXML-MaintenanceRequest xmlns="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16"
            xmlns:radiant="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
            xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/test">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>           
        </NAXML-MaintenanceRequest>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:ITTDetailExtension//*">
        <xsl:element name="radiant:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/ns0:NAXML-MaintenanceRequest/ns0:ItemMaintenance/ns0:ITTDetail/ns0:ITTDetailExtension/ns0:InventoryItem/ns0:Description">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Output -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NAXML-MaintenanceRequest xmlns="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:radiant="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension">
  <TransmissionHeader>
    <StoreLocationID />
    <VendorName />
    <VendorModelVersion />
  </TransmissionHeader>
  <ItemMaintenance>
    <TableAction />
    <RecordAction />
    <ITTDetail>
      <RecordAction />
      <ItemCode>
        <POSCodeFormat />
        <POSCode />
        <POSCodeModifier />
      </ItemCode>
      <ITTData>
        <ActiveFlag />
        <InventoryValuePrice />
        <MerchandiseCode />
        <RegularSellPrice />
        <FamilyCode />
        <ItemType>
          <ItemTypeCode />
          <ItemTypeSubCode />
        </ItemType>
        <LinkCode />
        <PaymentSystemsProductCode />
        <SalesRestrictCode />
        <SellingUnits />
        <TaxStrategyID />
      </ITTData>
      <ITTDetailExtension>
        <radiant:ModifierID />
        <radiant:DeviceGroupID />
        <radiant:CondimentItemListID />
        <radiant:ComboItemListID />
        <radiant:SalesRestrictionStrategyID />
        <radiant:InventoryItem>
          <Description/>
          <radiant:PriceUOMFactor />
        </radiant:InventoryItem>
        <radiant:ProhibitOnPOSFlag />
      </ITTDetailExtension>
    </ITTDetail>
  </ItemMaintenance>
</NAXML-MaintenanceRequest>
```

Output I am getting from the XSLT is -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NAXML-MaintenanceRequest xmlns="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:radiant="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension">
  <TransmissionHeader>
    <StoreLocationID />
    <VendorName />
    <VendorModelVersion />
  </TransmissionHeader>
  <ItemMaintenance>
    <TableAction />
    <RecordAction />
    <ITTDetail>
      <RecordAction />
      <ItemCode>
        <POSCodeFormat />
        <POSCode />
        <POSCodeModifier />
      </ItemCode>
      <ITTData>
        <ActiveFlag />
        <InventoryValuePrice />
        <MerchandiseCode />
        <RegularSellPrice />
        <FamilyCode />
        <ItemType>
          <ItemTypeCode />
          <ItemTypeSubCode />
        </ItemType>
        <LinkCode />
        <PaymentSystemsProductCode />
        <SalesRestrictCode />
        <SellingUnits />
        <TaxStrategyID />
      </ITTData>
      <ITTDetailExtension>
        <radiant:ModifierID />
        <radiant:DeviceGroupID />
        <radiant:CondimentItemListID />
        <radiant:ComboItemListID />
        <radiant:SalesRestrictionStrategyID />
        <radiant:InventoryItem>

          <radiant:PriceUOMFactor />
        </radiant:InventoryItem>
        <radiant:ProhibitOnPOSFlag />
      </ITTDetailExtension>
    </ITTDetail>
  </ItemMaintenance>
</NAXML-MaintenanceRequest>
```

It is deleting the Description tag from the xml.
Any help on the above xslt shall be highly appreciated.

I have tried many other ways but still no luck.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxend of postxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, this will provide the required output you show:

**XSLT1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16"
xmlns="http://www.naxml.org/POSBO/Vocabulary/2003-10-16" 
xmlns:radiant="http://www.radiantsystems.com/NAXML-Extension"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/test"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:NAXML-MaintenanceRequest">
    <NAXML-MaintenanceRequest>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>           
    </NAXML-MaintenanceRequest>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:ITTDetailExtension/* | ns0:PriceUOMFactor">
    <xsl:element name="radiant:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thank you for your response, however it is not working.

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful description. How is the result here different from the one you expect? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aB9NLr

Comment: Hi Michael, Your xslt code is working fine. I was trying this in eclipse and i guess the parser I am using was not supporting the xslt.